# Strange localization problem

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, malware, malware-detection

I spent several months in a foreign country (Ukraine).  Now, many websites that I visit (at least the ones that support it) default to Russian.  I'm worried that I might have some type of malware on my system (Mac OSX 10.6.5).

How can I go about discovering the root cause of this?  I've checked out my linux process list and don't see anything that seems out of the ordinary running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the "Language & Text" preference pane and check where Russian is in the list; all the languages there are considered, in order, when displaying things.

Firefox has its own version of that, also; in FF4, Preferences > Content and click the button at the lower right to display the preferred languages list.